# How to scrape when parents are similar but not the same

Tags: web-scraping

How would you scrape the titles and links of this website if the parents are not named the same?

[image]

For example, as you can see form the screenshot, the first title and link are inside div class="slot type-post type-order-1". For the second title and link, they are inside div class="slot type-post type-order-2" and so on.

The site is https://thechive.com/

If there's no solution, I'd have a very long code, which doesn't seem to make sense like this:

```
content1 = soup.find_all('div', class_='slot type-post type-order-1')
content2 = soup.find_all('div', class_='slot type-post type-order-2')

for contents in content1:
    title1 = contents.find('h3', class_='post-title entry-title card-title').text
    link1 = contents.h3.a['href']
    print(title1)
    print(link1)

for content in content2:
    title2 = content.find('h3', class_='post-title entry-title card-title').text
    link2 = content.h3.a['href']
    print(title2)
    print(link2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a css selector using the `select` method.

```
soup.select('div[class*="slot type-post type-order-"]')
```

The `*=`  stands for `Contains`.

Ref:

- [CSS selector cheat sheet](https://devhints.io/css)
- https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('https://thechive.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
for content in soup.select('div[class*="slot type-post type-order-"]'):
    title = content.find('h3', class_='post-title entry-title card-title').text
    link = content.h3.a['href']
    print(title)
    print(link)
```

Output:

```
GAPs can help keep you warm through this winter freeze (45 Photos)
https://thechive.com/2021/02/15/gaps-can-help-keep-you-warm-through-this-winter-freeze/
Texans REALLY do not know how to handle a little snow (20 Photos)
https://thechive.com/2021/02/15/texans-really-do-not-know-how-to-handle-a-little-snow-20-photos/
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It worked. I'm curious, when scraping do you always need to use the immediate parent in order to extract the title and website? For example, can we use div class='cards-content' which is the bigger parent that includes 'div[class*="slot type-post type-order-"]'?